# Delete all data from a table after selecting all data from the same table

Tags: sql, database, oracle

All i want is to select all rows from a table and once it is selected and displayed, the data residing in table must get completely deleted. The main concern is that this must be done using sql only and not plsql. Is there a way we can do this inside a package and call that package in a select statement? Please enlighten me here.

Dummy Table is as follows:

```
   ID   NAME   SALARY   DEPT
==================================
   1    Sam    50000     HR
   2    Max    45000     SALES
   3    Lex    51000     HR
   4    Nate   66000     DEV
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Select * from table; delete from table where 1=1; --OR-- truncate table;?

Comment: it displays the data but never deletes it. by the way, thanks for help.

Comment: Do you commit? ^.^

Comment: It has to display the data anyhow, and delete the data so that next data record can be inserted for next transaction. It is possible and quite easily but not when you are restricted to use only sql. The engine or (say) tool where i have to put the query accepts only sql and nothing else, When i write a two liner like - select * from mytable; delete from mytable where 1=1; it throws an error saying invalid charecter ";" Maybe it's the tool that would not be appropriate for the required results.

Comment: Well two liner is not exactly plsql syntax, so that has to be limitation of the tool. Perhaps you need two send two queries separately. But such a two line query is proper sql code. But I understand you are looking for something else.

Answer (score 0):

select  * from Table_Name;

Delete from Table_Name

Answer (score 0):

To select the data from a SQL query try using a pipelined function.

The function can define a cursor for the data you want (or all the data in the table), loop through the cursor piping each row as it goes.

When the cursor loop ends, i.e. all data has been consumed by your query, the function can perform a TRUNCATE table.

To select from the function use the following syntax;

```
SELECT * 
FROM   TABLE(my_function)
```

See the following Oracle documentation for information pipelined functions - https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28425/pipe_paral_tbl.htm

Comment: fetching the rows is not a concern but when i try to perform a delete DML inside a function, oracle restricts me throwing an error saying 'Cannot perform a DML operation inside a query.

Comment: OK. I didn't try the delete myself but that message does make sense. I would suggest that this may well not be possible in the way that you want it (without PL/SQL that is).

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done inside a package, because " this must be done using sql only and not plsql". A package *is* PL/SQL.

However it is very simple. You want two things: select the table data and delete it. Two things, two commands.

```
select * from mytable;
truncate mytable;
```

(You could replace `truncate mytable;` with `delete from mytable;`, but this is slower and needs to be followed by `commit;` to confirm the deletion and end the transaction.)

Comment: this does not solve the problem, it does not display and delete at the same time.

Comment: So what *is* the problem? I imagine an app: 1. it selects the data; 2. it deletes the data; 3. if all went well, it shows the data. What would be so bad with this approach? Why would it not suffice?

Comment: It has to display the data anyhow, and delete the data so that next data record can be inserted for next transaction. It is possible and quite easily but not when you are restricted to use only sql. The engine or (say) tool where i have to put the query accepts only sql and nothing else, When i write a two liner like -

select * from mytable;
delete from mytable where 1=1;

it throws an error saying invalid charecter ";"

Maybe it's the tool that would not be appropriate for the required results.

Answer (score 0):

**Without pl/sql it's not possible**.

Using pl/sql you can create  a function which will populate a row, and then delete

Here is example :

```
drop table tempdate;
create table tempdate as
select '1' id from dual
UNION
select '2' id from dual


CREATE TYPE t_tf_row AS OBJECT (
  id           NUMBER
);


CREATE TYPE t_tf_tab IS TABLE OF t_tf_row;




CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_tab_tf RETURN t_tf_tab PIPELINED AS 
  PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
BEGIN
  FOR rec in (select * from tempdate) LOOP
    PIPE ROW(t_tf_row(rec.id));
  END LOOP;
  delete from  tempdate ; commit;
END;

select * from table(get_tab_tf)  -- it will populate and then delete

select * from tempdate   --you can check here result of deleting
```

Comment: i need to display the data to the user and then delete after wards.

Comment: yes,you can displays by populating row in function and parallel delete them

Comment: This is elegant solution, but can silently *eat* records that are inserted after the start of the query and before the start of the delete.

Comment: @Maritime Bomber : what do you mean by _**eat**_ records? can you please enlighten us?

Comment: @hashir He mean, if you started query ,and then new records will inserted in query time, then new records will not deleted.

Comment: @hashir are you tried my code? is it ok for you? or any problems?

Comment: man your code code was pure _**pl-sql**_, which was the restriction for me. Only an _**sql**_ query would be acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

you can use below query

```
select * from Table_demo delete from Table_demo
```

Answer (score 0):

The feature you seek is [`SERIALIZABLE ISOLATION LEVEL`.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40540/consist.htm#CNCPT1320) This feature enables **repeatable reads**, which in particular guarantee that both `SELECT`and `DELETE`will read and process the same identical data.

Example

```
Alter session set isolation_level=serializable;

select * from tempdate;  

--- now insert from other session a new record

delete from  tempdate ; 
commit;

-- re-query the table old records are deleted, new recor preserved.
```

Comment: he want delete records when the select statements is end, with one query

Comment: @Kamil in a long term the number or selected record should equal to the number of inserted recored. This is guarantied by this solution, other aproaches can *leak* records, i.e. you could insert a record that is never selected.

Comment: In function we can block inserting new rows, I think your solution is answer for other question.

Comment: The solution you provided is somewhat relevant to the problem but not exactly, still a many thanks.
@Kamil gets my problem but i think there is no solution possible due to the limitation of tool i am using. Thank you for your efforts by the way.

Comment: Then what you mean when saying " inside a package and call that package in a select statement? "